# Aggregate column based on comparison with array in Hive

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql

Assume I have a hive table that looks like this:

```
|ID |CODE           |AMT  |NEW AMT|
|---|---------------|-----|-------|
|1  |['a','b',,,]   |10   |   50  |
|2  |[,,,'a','b']   |20   |   70  |
|3  |[,'c','d','e',]|30   |   20  |
|4  |['p','q',,,]   |40   |   20  |
```

The code column is of an array datatype. It can have 5 values and these values are being populated by an ETLjob. These values are comma separated.
I need to find the aggregated value of AMT column keeping the following conditions in place:

1. if the code has values 'a', 'b' then the value in amount for that id should be zero.
2. if the code has values 'c','d','e' then the value in amount should be replaced with the value
   that is  in new amt.
3. if it doesn't match either of the above conditions, the value should be same as that in amt.
   After this, the sum of amt can be taken. So with the table given above, the sum(amt) should be 60.

I have been struggling with this as I am new to hql/sql.
I have tried summing up using a case statement but failed.
Thank you for any input you may have!

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that you get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 1):

> "The code column is of an array datatype."

Use array_contains() function with case expressions:

```
select t.id, t.code, 
       case when array_contains(t.code, 'a') and array_contains(t.code, 'b')  then 0
            when array_contains(t.code, 'c') and array_contains(t.code, 'd') and array_contains(t.code, 'e') then t.new_amt
           else t.amt
       end AMT
  from table_name t
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `if else` or `case when`

Lets create a table with the sample data you provided

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `code` longtext NOT NULL,
 `amt` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `new_amt` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB   DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`, `code`, `amt`, `new_amt`) VALUES
(1, '[\'a\',\'b\',,,]', 10, 50),
(2, '[,,,\'a\',\'b\']', 20, 70),
(3, '[,\'c\',\'d\',\'e\',]', 30, 20),
(4, '[\'p\',\'q\',,,]', 40, 20);
```

See how the table looks like `SELECT * FROM table1`

| id | code | amt | new_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ['a','b',,,] | 10 | 50 |
| 2 | [,,,'a','b'] | 20 | 70 |
| 3 | [,'c','d','e',] | 30 | 20 |
| 4 | ['p','q',,,] | 40 | 20 |

Now use `if else` to decide the value

```
SELECT
    `code`,
    IF(
        `code` LIKE "%a','b%",
        0,
        IF(
            `code` LIKE "%c','d','e%",
            `new_amt`,
            `amt` + `new_amt`
        )
    ) AS price
FROM
    `table1`
```

**Result :**

| id | code | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ['a','b',,,] | 0 |
| 2 | [,,,'a','b'] | 0 |
| 3 | [,'c','d','e',] | 20 |
| 4 | ['p','q',,,] | 60 |